# Can't connect Java desktop app and Android app by USB

Tags: java, android

I can't find any solution for connecting Android app and desktop app with USB.

I need to send data to Android app from my desktop software by USB.
The best solution permit me to directly talk with my Android app to send JSON object, else send file on the smartphone.

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Easier with Bluetooth.  Cause then you can start with the Bluetooth chat sample app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is only possible via ADB (Android Debug Bridge).
You will need to enable USB Debugging on your android device for this to work.
Also the android adb executable must be present on the desktop pc.
(You can probably ship it with your desktop app executables, if you need to.)

The communication itself will work via tcp sockets. Your android app has to listen on
a tcp port and your desktop app has to open the connection on that port.

For this to work, you will have to forward the tcp port from the desktop pc to the android device via this adb command:

```
adb forward tcp:6100 tcp:7100
```

You can change the ports to your needs. The first one is the port on the desktop pc and the second one is the one to which the communication will be forwarded to on the android device.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports

EDIT: The good thing about this is that you can easily omit the USB connection and instead use a local network if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Great, I finnaly use ADB and it's work fine. I can send object directly to my Android application.

Desktop class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import callbacks.MainCallbacks;

public class UsbConnect {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in = null;

    private boolean logged = false;
    private boolean play = true;

    private MainCallbacks callbacks;

    public UsbConnect(MainCallbacks callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(play) {
                    if(!logged) {
                        // Tentative d'ouverture du port 
                        if(!setPort()) {                        
                            continue;
                        }

                        // Tentative de connexion
                        if(connexion()) {
                            callbacks.pdaConnect();
                            logged = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(!testConnexion()) {
                            callbacks.pdaDisconnect();
                            logged = false;
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void sendData(Object o) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(o);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callbacks.pdaDisconnect();
            logged = false;
        }
    }

    private void destroy() {
        play = false;

        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();

            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // NOTHING
        }
    }

    private boolean testConnexion() {
        try{
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException io){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean connexion() {
        try{
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 38300);

            try{
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                String message = (String) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("server>" + message);

            }
            catch (IOException io){
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e){
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean setPort() {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
            processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\Users\\Code\\Desktop\\adb.exe forward tcp:38300 tcp:38300");
            Process process;

            process = processBuilder.start();

            int exitVal = -12;

            try {
                exitVal=process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            if (exitVal == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My class listener when a device is connected on usb port, setup port adb, then it trying to connected with the socket server on smartphone.

> setPort() method it's to set port, you need to embbed adb.exe and its dll

Android class

```
server = new ServerSocket(38300);
client = server.accept();

out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
```

Source : https://github.com/user370305/Android-USB-Communication